# git rev-list HEAD~n does not include first commit in range

Tags: git, version-control

I'm using git rev-list to get a selection of commits from a repo in two different ways:

```
git rev-list --reverse HEAD~<n>..
```

and

```
git rev-list --reverse <tag1>..<tag2>
```

Having read the git rev-list manpage, I know that `<tag1>..<tag2>` is equivalent to `<tag2> ^<tag1>`, and that this will not include `<tag1>` in the range of commits selected, however the man page didn't specify what to do if I wanted an inclusive range of commits (that is, including `<tag1>`)

I have the same problem with:

```
 git rev-list --reverse HEAD~<n>..
```

Here is a specification of what I want:

say I have four commits:

```
A--B--C--D
```

and I have a script which I give two commits:

```
myscript --from B --to D
```

I want a list of commits of size 3:

```
B, C, D
```

or if I did:

```
myscript --last 4
```

I'd get:

```
A, B, C, D
```

My proposed solution was to do something like:

```
git rev-list --reverse <tag1>~1..<tag2>
```

or

```
git rev-list --reverse HEAD~<n+1>..
```

however, this doesn't work if n == number of commits, or tag1 is the first commit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So for the --last N option, I found that the following works quite nicely:

    git rev-list --reverse HEAD -n <n>

Answer (score 7):

So for the --last N option, I found that the following works quite nicely:

```
git rev-list --reverse HEAD -n <n>
```

Unfortunately, the solution to selecting an inclusive range isn't as clean:

```
git rev-list --reverse <tag1>..<tag2> --boundary
```

this will give you what you want, *however* it will put a small dash ("-") in front of the first commit. This can be solved with a bit of string processing though.

Answer (score 0):

From the `rev-list` man page:

> List commits that are reachable by following the parent links from the given commit(s), but **exclude commits that are reachable from the one(s) given with a ^ in front of them.**

To get an inclusive list of commits, just list the two references separated by a space. Your first reference should reference the previous commit with a tilda `~` and then be excluded which is denoted with a leading circumflex `^`

```
git rev-list --reverse ^<tag1>~ <tag2>
```

For example:

```
git log --oneline
```

> ```
> 071f2c5 (HEAD -> master) D
> 8b2c3ee C
> 4f9aa7e B
> 6296bbd A
> ```

```
git rev-list --reverse ^4f9aa7e~ 071f2c5
```

> ```
> 4f9aa7e4d421e7cad3113bf92967cb646484ea25
> 8b2c3eeb38b21b5cf143e9a79c21bf23453eef85
> 071f2c527712d8d16aede35e1881a07fb55b408f
> ```